# Jquery validate csv file

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

i try validate csv file when user upload file with extension/format CSV

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form1').validate({
        rules: { csv: { required: true, accept: "csv"  }},
        messages: { csv: "File must be CSV" }
    }); 
});
</script>

<form action="product_import.php?action=import" method="POST" name="form1" id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" />
</form>
```

But the problem is when i upload file with extension csv this error message will show up `File must be CSV`  , i dont know why this script can't accept even i set to `accept: "csv"` .

My csv file name is `product.csv`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The `accept` rule](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/accept#mimetype) is not for file extensions, it's for Mime types.

You might want to use [the `extension` rule instead](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/CustomMethods/extension#extension)

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/c5R3b/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#form1').validate({
        rules: {
            myfield: {
                required: true,
                extension: "csv"
            }
        }
    });

});
```

However, both of these rules require the inclusion of the [`additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js).

Comment: thanks @Sparky .. i already include additional-methods.js file just need to change  extension: "csv" .. again thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is something worked for me with plain JS approach.
Might be helpful for someone,

```
if( document.getElementById("csv").value.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf(".csv")==-1) 
{
        alert("Please upload a file with .csv extension.");
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. This is great!